# Comparing md5 checksums of the output of ls -la to detect file changes

Tags: linux, bash, md5, ls

Would taking an md5 checksum of a directory listing, as in:

```
ls -la | md5
```

be an efficient and accurate way to look for file changes within a directory?

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: It would be very efficient, but not at all accurate. It would have both false positives (when output changes from `Oct 23 12:34` to `Oct 23 2017`, or when timezone/locale changes),  and false negatives (changes to ACLs, changes to fs but not the files, changes with small timezone deltas).

Answer (score 2):

This would likely work most of the time, but, would not protect against the case that a file changed within the same minute and ended up with the same size.

Would the `inotify` program work for you?  See this thread:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/541128/monitor-folder-contents-changes

For what its worth, you could md5 each file within a directory, then md5 the resulting set..  Not efficient, but would catch edge cases.  See below:

```
[user@local ~/tmp] find . -type f  -exec md5sum {} \;
e4982b4d6725d408d405f9800fdb4b77 *./1.txt
beb755b5b40ff3b449100455b96c937e *./2.txt
2466877a535c4f16bbec375f3085ab8d *./3.txt

[user@local ~/tmp] find . -type f  -exec md5sum {} \; | md5sum
c73e5ae62984d69c94b5b24d75c07025 *-
```